# Jigsaw Puzzle, cutting pieces from image

Tags: algorithm, puzzle

I'm trying to make an application that cuts image into jigsaw puzzles. My problem is that I don't know how to do this (any kind of algorithm). I do want to have male and female endings of puzzles, but not in the same place all the time (like in the middle of puzzle border) so this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755389/how-to-create-jigsaw-image-puzzle-using-c solution doesn't fit me.

Is there any kind of "smart" algorithm to make this happens. I was thinking about using bezier curves, but I don't know how to do this right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a random offset. You store for each side the kind of interaction (ie male or female), the anchor type (you could use a set of different looking "anchors" (don't know the name), and the offset.

This make for easy check : you must have same anchor, same offset and different kind for the two piece to be able to link.

regards
Guillaume

Comment: Checking pieces is much simpler. You just need to number your pieces and assign each piece a number of it's neighbours, then you just check your numbers.

Comment: didn't even thought of that ! Sometime the obvious is really harder to see. Thanks for the remark

Answer (score 2):

There is a sketch of how I'd approach it here: [How to create jigsaw puzzle from an image using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067566/how-to-create-jigsaw-puzzle-from-an-image-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Randomization is your savior! Won't randomizing the position of the curve help?

Comment: Maybe... but I was thinking... there are some bezier curves which can produce an 3d egg... so maybe there are some that with a little randomization could produce a puzzle line (horizontally and vertically mixed).