# Objective c dynamically split image into irregular jigsaw shapes

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to split an image into multiple irregular shaped **jigsawed** chunks. Though I am able to split into multiple rectangular shaped pieces but not able to find any way to for irregular shapes. I have come across [Jigsaw Puzzle, cutting pieces from image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583776/jigsaw-puzzle-cutting-pieces-from-image) but none has any implementation or idea in objective c. Please give me some idea

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract arbitrarily shaped portions of an image, you can do it by compositing. I wrote a [sample code project](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/Cropped_Image/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000388) many years ago  that demonstrates how to do so.

Comment: thought I could n't able to open this project in my XCode 4 dues to version issue but I think I can achieve the same cropping using masking e.g. CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask(UIImage.CGImage, mask);

Comment: I finally could able to implement it. I had take help of mask images and then apply some mathematics to cut pieces of main image then apply mask. It was really worth of effort.

Comment: @CoolCoder: can you share with me that part of code,i am also stuck on it.Thanks.

Comment: @M.S.B Do you still looking for information. Its been a while since I last visited

Comment: This question is the third hit on google for xcode jigsaw help. Please post your code so that others can see it in the future.